Graphic issues on Ubuntu
I've been attempting to install Ubuntu on my old PC. However, I consistently encounter graphic glitches on background images, menus, missing wallpaper, or overall screen glitches. (I've tried various LTS versions of Ubuntu: 24.04, 22.04, 20.04, 18.04, 16.04)
My attempts to update drivers from within Ubuntu were unsuccessful as no updates were available. So, I tried downloading and installing updates manually from the Nvidia website. However, I encountered several errors during installation, some of which I was able to resolve, but not all.
Some of the error messages during the manual driver installation: Unable to find the development tool cc ..., The cc version check failed ..., Unable to find the development tool make ..., Unable to build the nvidia kernel module ..., and etc.
Hardware Specifications: GIGABYTE GA-M61PME-SP2 - NVIDIA GeForce 6100 / nForce 430
What suggestions do you have to solve this problem? Any insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Please be precise with details; you mention a load of releases; many being EOL or EOSS & thus off-topic here, but aren't clear as to what exactly you tried other than vague mention of release. I'm involved in QA; and know from experience 18.04 would run on a specific old devices I have/used if 4.15, 4.18, & 5.0 kernel ISOs were installed, but would have problems if a 18.04 using 5.3 (& above) on one device, and 5.4 on another device.. yet all kernel versions I mentioned were available for 18.04. For 20.04 the kernels available are 5.4, 5.8, 5.11, 5.13 & 5.15 but you only mention the release

We'll be more able to help if you're specific with details; details about your hardware & clear details as to what ISO you tried (or at least full details such as Ubuntu 22.04.4 Desktop ISO) as there are many ISOs, and I've found on older (newer too) hardware a lot more is helpful than just the release detail, but specifically what you tried  (or are you saying you tried 5+ different ISOs for each LTS release you mention thus covered all kernel stack options?)

I downloaded them from the Desktop image section at Alternative downloads

There might be a hardware issue with the NVIDIA GPU / graphics card.

Its probable given your (where downloaded comment) that you downloaded the latest HWE image for each release; but providing file-names allows us to know rather than make educated-guesses. For older hardware, I'd have opted for older kernel stacks (ie. GA for each release meaning you're using two year older kernels! and I'd only have tried supported releases).  I don't know your hardware sorry

To allow installation of drivers that has proprietary code (e.g. from nvidia):

Hit the Super(Win)-key,
begin type Additional drivers and
a green icon (with that text) should appear; click on it.
Select Ubuntu software and
make sure there is a tick for proprietary drivers ...
select Additional drivers - you might need to wait slightly get the display updated...
Make your choice;

... currently the "safe" one seem to be Nouveau.
The 535 and 495(?) versions of nVidia has been stated as "flakey" in some posts here.
Select any one you have available,
do reboot and try verify if it works for your hardware and OS.
Overall, I'd recommend; try to stay on 24.04 - just for longevity if nothing else.

Thank you very much, I will definitely try this solution.
Is 24.04 suitable for a system with 1GB of RAM in term of performance? Is it possible that may be slow?

1GB is a bit limited, check if you can find e.g. Xubuntu 24.04 - I'd expect it to have a lower memory overhead / requirement. Google that.
